# gradle: application plugin and custom main-class attribute

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

my build.gradle has the following tasks:

```
jar {
manifest {
    attributes "Main-Class": "io.aa.Zz" 
    attributes "Build-Version": version 
}}
```

together with

```
run { mainClassName = "org.jvnet.hk2.generator.HabitatGenerator" }
```

my problem is that mainClassName replaces the preset value in output jar's manifest. is there any solution for this?

Comment: Why do you have different main classes for run and manifest?

Comment: well, the main class in the manifest is the class to be triggered to start the application. the class in run is related to hk2 dependency injector and is used to created its internal descriptor files during the build.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run a java class during your build? The application plugin is likely not the right way to do that. You should instead define a task of type `JavaExec`